# OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter get token

Tags: oauth-2.0, vaadin, spring-oauth2

How can I get token from backend java server

I have a oauth server authentication and I can login successfully with Spring security layer. I get toke in web browser client via http get request...

https://x.x.x.x/oxauth/restv1/token

How can I get token in backend part using OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter class?

```
/**
     * Called after executed Configuration "addFilterBefore"
     *
     * @return OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter
     */
    private OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oauthFilter() {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oauthFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/login");

        // OAuth2RestTemplate > Spring Boot does not automatically create such a bean,
        OAuth2RestTemplate oauthTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(oauth(), oauth2ClientContext);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(oauthResource().getUserInfoUri(), oauth().getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(oauthTemplate);

        oauthFilter.setRestTemplate(oauthTemplate);
        oauthFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);

        return oauthFilter;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that... oauthApplication.getOauth2ClientContext().getAccessToken()